# Filter table by two (mm) tables in TYPO3 (Doctrine)

Tags: php, mysql, database, doctrine, typo3

I have the following Tables:

One Table with addresses:

```
| uid | name | ...
```

One with brands:

```
| uid | uid_parent | ...
```

And one with models

```
| uid | uid_parent | ...
```

Now I want to get the addresses which sells the brands with uid = 1,2 and models with uid = 1,2.

I got a solution to get all addresses by **one** of these conditions with the following code, but not I have no Idea how to solve that for **both** conditions in Doctrine:

```
$queryBuilder
->select('*')
->from('addresses');
->innerJoin(
  'addresses',
  'models',
  'models'
)
->expr()->eq('models.uid_parent', $queryBuilder->quoteIdentifier('addresses.uid'))
->where(
  $queryBuilder->expr()->in('uid', $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter([1,2], Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY))
)
->groupBy('addresses.uid');
->add('having','count(models.uid = 2)')
```

Comment: I may be mistaken or have misunderstood your question, but shouldn't you be able to just do multiple joins and filter by adding additional where clauses like so, prefixing the uid in your where clause with the table names:
`->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->in('models.uid', [...]))`